# Algebraic varieties associated to finite groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Have the following equations been studied in the literature?

Let $G$ be a finite group.

Then I am looking for functions $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}~ \backslash \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace $ such that

$$\sum_{h \in G} \left(\frac{f(gh)}{f(g)f(h)} - 1 \right) = 0, ~~\text{ for all $g$ in } G$$ .

Comment: Uhm.. where are the algebraic varieties?

Comment: I'm guessing the variety is living in $(\mathbb{A}^1 - \{0\})^G$, where the coordinates are the $f(g)$ where $g$ runs through $G$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I initially thought the $f$'s (with the zero function too) would make a ring whose Spec was the alg. var. in question, but the $f$'s don't form a ring ($1$ is in the set but $1+1$ is not).

Comment: In other words, the average value of each $h \mapsto f(g h)f(h)^{-1} - f(g)$ is $0$.